# python - Year-week combination for the end or beginning of a year

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I want to construct YYYY_WW information from dates (where WW is a number of week). I am struggling with the years' endings (beginnings), where a part of a week can fall into the neighbouring year:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# generate range of dates and extract YYYY_WW
dates_range = pd.date_range(start='2018-12-29', end='2019-01-02')
weeks = dates_range.strftime("%Y_%V")
print(weeks)

#Index(['2018_52', '2018_52', '2018_01', '2019_01', '2019_01'], dtype='object')
```

`2018_01` is obviously incorrect. Any hint for a simple workaround?

Comment: What behavior do you want? ISO definition, meaning 2018-12-31 is in week 1 of 2019?

Comment: I need `['2018_52', '2018_52', '2019_01', '2019_01', '2019_01']`, which should be in line with ISO, see e.g. [here](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar_text_2.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `%G` directive:

> ISO 8601 year with century representing the year that contains the
>   greater part of the ISO week (%V).

See [strftime() and strptime() behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for details.

For example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dates_range = pd.date_range(start='2018-12-29', end='2019-1-2')
weeks = dates_range.strftime('%G_%V')
print(weeks)
# Index(['2018_52', '2018_52', '2019_01', '2019_01', '2019_01'], dtype='object')
```